# Send email with Java, Gmail and Bouncy Castle Provider

Tags: java, security, gmail, provider, jakarta-mail

I try to send an email using the next code:

```
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
...
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");        
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
...
Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
try {
     t.connect();
     t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
     System.out.println("Done");
 } finally {
     t.close();
 }  
 ...
```

But it throws the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
```

If I don't add the provider it works fine, but I need it in my code for other issues.

```
//Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: You must have to add Provider else how come JVM knows the algorithm ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I think javax.mail has default providers. You don't need to add any provider in order to send an email (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#gmail). I do it in other class and for other questions, but it seems to be a conflict when I try to send an email.